# Google App Engine JDO Question: Memory Consumption Of Large List In Same Fetch Group

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am creating a web application using GAE and I'm using JDO to access the datastore. For simplicity's sake here's a description of my data structure:

**Book Class**

```
public class Book 
{

....

public List<Word> getAllWords()
{
return m_lAllWordsInBook;
}

...

@Persistent(mappedBy="m_bPrintedIn", defaultFetchGroup="true")
@Element(dependent = "true")
List<Word> m_lAllWordsInBook;
}
```

**Word Class**

```
public class Word
{
..
@Persistent
Book m_bPrintedIn;
}
```

I haven't found a way to only load parts of a dependent list (in the same fetch group) automatically through JDO. For example, this means that even if a user is only viewing page 4 of a book, they must still obtain all the words in a 500 page book beforehand. Testing on my local machine is working out fine and I'm not noticing any performance issues when performing Datastore calls to retrieve "Books" with many "Words" but I fear what will happen at scale.

**Now, here's my question:** What would happen in a hypothetical scenario where there are thousands of simultaneous users all retrieving their own copy of various "Books" (each with many words)? Would it not be a major strain on memory?  Is it a better idea to simply make direct queries from the DataStore (ex. `SELECT FROM WORDS WHERE BOOK_ID==BOOK_XYZ`) with a `Query.setRange()` that is reasonable in size (ex. the number of words on a page)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE's implementation of JDO does not allow to retrieve partial objects. You could store chapters or pages individually using a key that is a combination of the book title and the page number, and then retrieving only that object instead of the whole book. Your class book would then contain only a list of keys for the different chapters, or the number of pages.

Anyhow, those thousands of users would be retrieving the books in thousands of clients, then diluting the memory strain. You will need to test what is lighter to your server, either sending whole books at once (possibly a longer process, perhaps wasting some bandwidth) or having to deal with multiple requests for each page. Perhaps sending chapters is a good middle solution.

Comment: Hmm, interesting point but I'd be interested in having you explain the statement _"diluting the memory strain"_ a bit more. 

The memory consumption I'm most concerned with is the server side memory consumption. Each user would essentially have a copy of a book thus the total memory consumption would equal **Number of Users x Memory Consumption Per Book**. As a result, the amount of memory consumed would increase greatly if either of those two variables increased.

Comment: @Yohannes maybe I assumed too much: I'm thinking you have a servlet sending the book as a response to an ajax call from some client. The server reads it, sends it, and forgets about it. If that's not the case, and the book is handled by some long term process in the server, then please disregard that phrase. Anyhow, I would not worry much about straining Google servers. And remember, you're being charged for CPU time and bandwidth, not for memory usage AFAIK.

Comment: @Aleadm ahh, yes, I should have been more clear about that. I store the object in session afterwards hence my initial concern. No ajax here.

You're certainly right about the cost issue and perhaps I'm thinking too far ahead in terms of the server strain. As per your recommendation, I'll go ahead and test what makes sense. I think I'm going to go for a hybrid solution that retrieves full objects in some scenarios and part objects (via direct queries) in others. In the end, what matters most is the users experience and not necessarily the _how we got to the users experience_. Thanks.

Comment: @Yohannes yes, a good hybrid solution should give you the best of both worlds. Remember also that your app will be hosted by many servers at the same time, most probably even in different locations. I would really not worry about memory, but CPU usage.

Comment: Correction: actually JDO does *not* prevent retrieving partial objects. Google's plugin maybe doesn't allow it, but then that is their implementation only.

Comment: @DataNucleus, is there any documentation on how to go about this?

Comment: @DataNucleus correct me if I'm wrong, but at least you would need to have several List fields and retrieve each one separately. And yes, you're right, I'm talking about GAE's JDO implementation. I will correct that in the answer.

Comment: @Yohannes How to do it with GAE/J? No idea since its Google's plugin, so you're dependent on what they offer you; ask them maybe. With other datastores that we support the returned List can be a proxy and can be set up to not cache entries in the list, so only returning them as the user iterates.

Comment: @Aleadam, JDO doesn't prevent the user "loading" (iterating through) certain elements in the List and then when detaching the implementation could have an option in their SCO List handler to just detach those, and if accessing an element of a List where the element is not detached then throw exception as per the JDO spec; very feasible, but not coded up.  Obviously the user could split their "List" up into multiple and then just detach the ones that are required (or in the users case insert a class called Chapter ;-) so then they can detach more manageable parts)

Comment: @DataNucleus, thanks for the info. I was unaware that that was possible (re: not caching entires in the list and simply retrieving them upon iteration). Now, time to verify if that's indeed possible on GAE's JDO implementation.

For the time being, I've decided to move ahead with retrieving the "Words" using the `Query.execute()` and `setRange()` approach for this particular scenario and the `Query.execute()` with `defaultFetchGroup=true` for scenarios where the contained lists are much smaller in size.

Comment: @DataNucleus thanks for the explanation. All I know of JDO is GAE's implementation, which is quite limited at the moment. Hopefully they'll improve it with time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for lazy loading of Container fields.
Have a look into [Datanucleus - Container fields : Lazy Loading](http://www.datanucleus.org/plugins/core/sco.html)

Comment: I detach the "Book" objects for processing by the application as soon as the object has been retrieved from the DataStore. As such, lazy-loading will not help me much in this scenario, unless there was a way to lazy-load only a subset of the SCO before detaching the object and I don't think the link you provided makes any mention of such a capability.

Comment: @Yohannes Do you really need to detach your objects ? Can your application process your objects without detaching ?

Comment: for whatever reason, I'm just seeing your last comment. From a practical standpoint, in some cases, I certainly need to detach the object but in some others, I don't absolutely need to. From a technical/business standpoint, I have decoupled the data access layer from the business logic layer for fear that I don't want to be glued to GAE's datastore. If I handle the business logic without detaching the object, then I am essentially coupling the two together.

I'm curious though, do you see a compelling reason for me to avoid detaching objects?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution to this is to go straight to the source and use low-level datastore, at least wherever you have a bottleneck {in this case, your List<Word>}.  I started out strictly JDO because it makes good sense to keep things object oriented.  However, low-level DS has tremendous power over pure JDO solutions {asynchronous, batched operations, and queries that you can iterate on as the results come in}.

To make a long story short, your performance problem is that you are storing an indexed list of Word entities in your Book {actually, an indexed list of Keys, but, I digress}.  If there are 500 words, you have 500 items in your list.  Not only must you load them all every time, the real performance hit {if this list is indexed} is that when you write these objects, it will cross-index all 500 of these entities and every write to a Book object will cost hundreds of write operations {and a lot of time}.  There is also a cap {somewhere around 1000, I think} for total write ops per entity, so a very large book might not even save at all.

What you want to do instead is to store each item of that list in it's own entity.  Convert the List<Word> field into a datastore table of its own, with a pointer back to the book it belongs in {as well as the Word's position in the list, since I'm guessing you want that data}. When you load a book, it will not have the Word list already filled.  You then fill it by performing a query.  If you want to load the whole thing, do not put a range on your query.  If you want lazy loading, only grab a couple hundred words, and send them back with a cursor from a QueryResultIterator to load the rest.  JDO stores the List as a List<Key>, and then just gets the entities by key and adds them to the list.  Pure entity gets are faster than queries, but massive List objects in entities is painfully slow and error-prone {google: appengine exponential explosion}.

Since I read in the comments you are caching the books in session, you could perform your lazy loading in the background.  Use one RPC to get the book and the first X words you need to show, then, have the client launch background RPCs to load up the rest of the results into session.  This way, the first query is a little slow {instead of uber-slow}, and all subsequent user-driven queries will already have their results preloaded and cached {uber-fast}.

It may seem counter intuitive to store more entities to have better performance, but I promise you, this method is *blazing fast* on appengine.  I can perform 20 fast requests in less realtime and less cost than performing one really slow request.  With more entities of fewer indexes, your writes and deletes will be much faster, and if you stick to low level DS, you can asynchronously load and batch your entities, or even run five queries at the same time {requires some hackery around detecting when the queries block and avoiding paying instance hours to wait on queries...  but it works, and saves us piles of money}.

JDO internally converts your list of entities into a list of keys anyway.  My suggestion is to remove this list of keys from your entity, and give it a table of it's own so you can control how much gets loaded.  This table is different from  your existing Word table in that it pertains to a particular word in a particular Book.  I'm not sure, but I think JDO will use the Book as the pojo Word's entity group parent.  Using entity group to encode the parent Book rather than a Book field means that you can retrieve the Book key from a keys only query, but the fact that you probably already know the Book id you are looking for means you can use a field or a parent key in your query.  If JDO already has your data formatted with parent keys, use them to avoid porting any data.

Look at the structure of your data created by JDO and ask yourself if you could load and query that data more efficiently.  If yes, then use some low-level magic to bypass the bulky "load everything at once" methodology.  If no, consider restructuring your data so you can get to it as efficiently as possible.  Moving a List<Object> to a lookup table of it's own unlocks the appengine key to scalability: Lots and lots of tiny requests.  Appengine loves small requests, and hates giant globs of memory that stick around for a long time.  The more you store in memory and the longer you store it, the poorer the performance of your instances.  I stream all my data around in low-level DS, and we pay ~30 instance hours a day to have six instances on and running at all times.  I'm not sure exactly what sorcery caused this cost reduction {threadsafe, async-everything or request minification}, but it saves us hundreds of dollars a month.